uncertain about postgresql lob migration data
So we have a springboot app using a postrgressql db.
We used to have some data that were mapped as CLOBs and BLOBs. Since we decided to move away from large objects we migrated the database and while doing so, we created some backup tables in case something went wrong.
Example from liquibase
<changeSet id="240123909061" author="zero" dbms="postgresql">
    <sql>
      CREATE TABLE data_files_backup (LIKE data_files );
      INSERT INTO data_files_backup SELECT * FROM data_files ;
    </sql>
  </changeSet>

  <changeSet id="240123909062" author="zero" dbms="postgresql">
    <addColumn tableName="data_files">
      <column name="context_new" type="BYTEA"/>
    </addColumn>
  </changeSet>

  <changeSet id="240123909063" author="zero" dbms="postgresql">
    <sql>
      UPDATE data_files SET context_new = lo_get(data_files.context::BIGINT) where data_files.context is not null;
    </sql>
  </changeSet>

  <changeSet id="240123909064" author="zero"  dbms="postgresql">
    <dropColumn tableName="data_files" columnName="context"/>
  </changeSet>

  <changeSet id="tm240909065" author="zero"  dbms="postgresql">
    <renameColumn tableName="data_files" oldColumnName="context_new" newColumnName="context"/>
  </changeSet>


Now that this stage is over, i want to drop every backup table.
There comes my confusion. So the changeset is like this
  <changeSet id="migration-backup-delete" author="me me" dbms="postgresql">
    <sql>
      DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data_files_backup;
     ..... 
     other tables
     .....
    </sql>
  </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>


I started the backend and everything seems fine. Then i wanted to cleanup also the db and i get
$ vacuumlo -n -U MYNAME -p 5438 CENTRALDB
Password: 
Connected to database "CENTRALDB"
Test run: no large objects will be removed!
Would remove 0 large objects from database "CENTRALDB".


Uppon looking to the pg_largeobject in the pg_catalog i realised that it is completly empty.
I thought you could either unlink the large objects and let the daemon do his work or remove them and then run vacuumlo for a cleanup.
Have i done something wrong ? When did the pg_largeobject got emptied?
EDIT -- pg_largeobject_metadata is also empty.

From vacuumlo: An orphaned large object (LO) is considered to be any LO whose OID does not appear in any oid or lo data column of the database.. I don't see anywhere that you do anything with the LO's referenced in data_files.context other then create a bytea copy of them in data_files.context_new.  If they are still linked to the data_files table they will not be cleaned up. You might want to look at pg_largeobject_metadata. LO's have permissions.

Hi I added the missing piece of code,  I drop and rename the column where the LOs used to be. So effectively they LOs only live now in the backup table, which i removed before vacuumlo

Hmm. at this point I don't know what is going on. I will need to think more on this.
